# Dropdown Submenus that Slide Up When Open

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, submenu

I am building a long menu that also contains submenus. Here's the link: http://ws2.5giants.com/ - shrink your browser down below 768 pixels to see the mobile view. In the dropdown menu, click "Sample" and you can the current menu behavior.

I am trying to copy the behavior on http://www.porsche.com/usa/ where when you click on a sub-menu item, that item scrolls to the top of the menu as the submenu expands. For example, shrink your window, open the window, and click "Models".

Does anyone know how they did this?

Thanks!

Comment: You could just add an `id` for that `<a>` tag and then make that the `href`. For instance, try making that sample link: `<a id="sample" href="#sample">`.

Answer (score 2):

Khargoosh is correct. When you click a menu item it collapses all the other menu items then scrolls to the top of the clicked item.

Try this:

Editied to show how to scroll back to the top when the dropdown is clicked to close it.

```
$(document).ready(function (){ 
    $('.dropdown-submenu a').click(function() {
        if($(this).parent().find('ul.dropdown-menu').is(':visible'))
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('navbar-nav').offset().top }, 600);
        }else{
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top }, 600);
    }); 
});
```

Give the credit to Steve from this post: [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Comment: This is getting closer... I added the code and it's almost working. The difference it is only working when you click on the 3rd level deep of the menu. For example: "Awesome Bike 1".

Comment: The list item "Sample" needs to scroll up and it also has the class "dropdown-submenu".

Comment: That code snippet is registering a click event. In order to do that you need to wrap it in the $(document).ready(function(){ ... click event code here .. } or the shortcut $(function(){ ... click event code here ... }.

Comment: Greg, like this? '$(document).ready(function (){
$('.dropdown-submenu').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 600);
});
});'

Comment: Yes. The jquery method $(document).ready(function(){ ... }); runs as soon as the DOM is fully loaded. This assures all objects matching the selector  of your event listeners are loaded before assigning the event listener to them. If the assignment of the event listener runs before your $('.dropdown-submenu') is part of the DOM the click event doesn't get assigned to it.

Comment: Weird. It's working, but still on the wrong link. Any ideas how I can get "Sample" to scroll up when clicked?

Comment: See if this works. Instead of adding the click event to the dropdown-submenu, which is the <li>. Add it to the anchor tag.change it to -         $(document).ready(function (){ $('.dropdown-submenu a').click(function() { $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top }, 600); }); });         -  You have a lot of click events going on when these menu options are clicked if any of these returns a false it will stop the rest from working. It's best to combine all these click event listeners into one.

Comment: Gregg thank you so much. That works great. '$(document).ready(function (){
$('.dropdown-submenu a').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 600);
});
});'

Comment: Any idea how I could reverse it? Meaning, when a "child" menu item is closed, then the menu scrolls back to the parent location?

Comment: Thanks again @GreggDuncan... that code didn't work. I tried substituting some different classes, but no luck. I ran it through js link and there were a couple of errors. http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php

Answer (score 0):

> when you click on a sub-menu item, that item scrolls to the top of the menu > as the submenu expands

I don't think this actually describes what is happening on the linked website.  To me, it looks like the inactive submenus are collapsed, the clicked submenu is expanded, and the windows scrolls **down** to the first entry.

You can use (for example) jQuery `.scrollTop()` to get the vertical scrollbar position for the clicked element and to then set the vertical scrollbar position to that element.